# VSCode Intellisense suggests filename in every string I type

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to tell VSCode Intellisense to only suggest files/folders if the context makes sense for that? I'm aware that the "file" and "folder" Intellisense features can be turned off individually (which I'm considering), but I'm wondering if there's any way to just limit their context.

That is, if I'm writing this:

```
def foo():
    with open(".gitignore") as f:
        pass
```

then I would understand (and maybe sometimes even appreciate) VSCode giving me file/folder suggestions.

However, most of the time, I'm writing this instead:

```
def foo():
    """<enter>
```

to start writing a docstring, and when I hit enter there, it autocompletes the first file in the list (invariably `.DS_Store`).

Here's a video showing this in real time:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ij_ZsDhUrDs

Comment: ignore the suggestion and keep on typing

Comment: What extensions do you have installed?

Comment: @rioV8 I did that; I "kept on typing" and hit enter, at which point the first suggestion in the list was inserted into my file. I prefer to type a docstring _after_ also typing the closing """ line, so that my file is syntactically valid while I'm typing.

Comment: @MattBierner plenty. I'm not sure if you really want me to write the exhaustive list, though. Is there something in particular I should look for?

Comment: Does it still happen when you disable extensions?

Comment: It does not. I also notice there's no Intellisense suggestions at all, though. I'd guess that the Python extension is what provides Intellisense for string literals in Python, but I'm not actually sure.

Comment: @Brett Higgins -Currently in VS Code, Python's "Intellisense" is provided by the "Python" extension, and you could refer to it: [IntelliSense in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_autocomplete-and-intellisense) In addition, the "Intellisense" provided by different language services is also different.